# Is there a way to mute all sound coming from a tab in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, audio

Is there a way to mute all sound coming from a tab in Firefox?

I want to be able to play games in my browser while listing to music on iTunes without the sound overlapping. I am using Firefox on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Vista or Windows 7 you can turn off sound for each program at sound mixer.

Or if you have XP or other OS you can use plugins.

For flash games you can use [Mute Flash](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5453) (FF plugin).

And [FlashMute](http://www.indev.no/?p=projects#flashmute) software.

Comment: i have a mac those are all for pc

Answer (score 0):

Click on the speaker to the right of the title in the tab:

See [*Mute sound in Firefox tabs*](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mute-sound-firefox-tabs) on the Firefox website for details and screenshots.